# How to load 2 different CSS file globally for header and body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 CSS files , first one is for Header and Footer. Second one is for Body.
If I load both of them , it creates issue in the body because of some conflicting class file.
Is there any way to load both the CSS globally but one CSS  will be only scoped for header & footer and it should not impact body. And the other one should be scoped for body.
I cannot use inline style.

Comment: The best solution is to change your CSS and HTML to either not use the same class or use CSS scope by changing your CSS like `.header .class` and `.body .class` etc..

Comment: I cannot change CSS as they are provided by external party. is there any way to use both the CSS globally yet scoped for separate section in a page. ?

Comment: I guess you could always load the header in an iframe, the footer in an iframe and the body in its own iframe. But it seems like I would reevaluate why you are in this position in the first place and see how the fix the problem instead of rigging it to work.

Comment: we receive third party css and include it in our JSP. our pages are already built using abc_v1.0.css , now they have released abc_v2.0.css which has some new design and conflicting classes (also not backward compatible). But we dont want to implement those new design in the body , we just want to use them in the Header & Footer. Body should remain as it is.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have something like that:

1st file (used for header and footer):

```css
.class-foo-bar {}
```

2nd file (used for body):

```css
.class-foo-bar {}
```

---

You can just scope by adding header before your class which gives this:

1st file (used for header and footer):

```css
header .class-foo-bar, footer .class-foo-bar {}
```

2nd file (used for body):

```css
body .class-foo-bar {}
```

Comment: I have 2 CSS files - 
1. abcV1.0.css -- should be used only for Header & Footer
2. abcV2.0.css -- Should be used only for Body
I cannot change CSS file as they are provided by external party, i can only modify js file or my JSP to provide different scope. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Can you add a sass/scss compiler to your project? I have a sort of idea, it's not pretty but it should work